# Twilio Programmable Chat: Listen to add new channel/messages in a chat room

Tags: twilio, chat, twilio-programmable-chat

I am building a chat room in my website, where a list of all the subscribed channels is loaded (using getSUbscribedChannels()) and when the user clicks on any chat, the messages are shown. Please note I am using private channels.

Now if a user is in the chat room and they are invited/added to a new channel through twilio REST api, how can I load the new private channel in the list of channels? How can the front-end js know that user is added to a new channel?

PS: I have tried memberAdded event in js, but since the user is added through REST api, the client in front-end doesn't listen to the event. Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: Yeah I added user from api and added a memberAdded/channelAdded event in js. But the js event doesn't execute when member was added through api.